Where are Qt tools after installing PySide6 on macOS?
After running pip3 install pyside6 on Windows, we can see many Qt tools under PySide6.

Where are these tools after installing PySide6 on macOS?
There is no result in the search.

please tell me where is the tools after installed pyside6 on macos.
===
Before ask this question, I have searched official document,
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tools/index.html#package-tools
there only intro for windows.

Look into the PySide6 folder in site-packages.

@musicamante there is nothing about the tools, just check my snapshoot.

That image is unclear and certainly incomplete; by the way, you should not upload images of code/data/errors to begin with. Also provide proper details about the specific OS/PySide version you have installed, and any relevant environment/install info (eg: if you're using a virtual env, custom Python setup, etc.).
